# what native fonts are there on a kindle?

Tags: kindle, fonts

I would like to publish an ebook which uses different fonts, but I don't want neither to embed them in the .mobi file nor have the user download them.

I am fairly sure that somewhere there should be a list of native fonts which may be used without problems, but I don't know where to search for it...

Comment: for the time being, I eventually found https://rogerpacker.com/how-to-choose-typography-for-ebooks/ with a list of fonts

Comment: Aha, already answered this question: https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/7143/what-are-serif-and-sans-serif-fonts-on-different-ebook-reading-systems