# How can a reading pad not come with the Times New Roman font?

Tags: fonts

I had to manually figure out how to copy over the Times New Roman font from my Windows machine to my new PocketBook InkPad Color. It had nothing like it selectable by default.

What could possibly explain this? Isn't Times New Roman literally *the* font used by virtually *all* real books for *eons*? Isn't that a weird thing to leave out?

(Also, how can there not be a "pocketbook" tag here?!)

Answer (score 1):

Times New Roman is a proprietary font and has to be licensed to distribute with a product. There's no font used by practically all books, and it's likely most standard serif fonts will be hard to distinguish at the resolution of an ebook reader.

Comment: So it's a legal thing? I guess that makes sense, but why not pay for such a common and beautiful font when you sell a commercial product? Also, no offence, but have you seen a modern PocketBook InkPad Color? I may have picked a large font size, but it's impossible for my eyes to distinguish any pixels. It looks like a printed paper.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [list of system fonts for reading systems up to about 2019](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/7143/what-are-serif-and-sans-serif-fonts-on-different-ebook-reading-systems). I do not think they have changed much. My guess is that device manufacturers don't like having a font which is practically everywhere. Also there are [comparable free/nonproprietary fonts available](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Times_New_Roman#Free_alternatives).